# Comments - Allow deletion of comments on your content without Administer Comments permission?

Tags: users, comments

Is there a way to allow users to delete comments that are on their own content without giving access to Administer Comments?

Example:

Authenticated user makes a blog post (or some node content)
Another Authenticated user comments on it

Author does not like comment- wishes to delete.

The only option I have is edit/reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be doable with the [User Comment](http://drupal.org/project/usercomment) module in Drupal 6, or the [Comment Access](http://drupal.org/project/commentaccess) module in Drupal 7. They both add permissions so that authors can approve, delete or administer comments on their own content.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be the use of the [nodecomment module](http://drupal.org/project/nodecomment) with Drupal 6. This way you have permission by contenttype like `delete own MYCOMMENT content`